# What do I put in these forms in the OAuth consent screen when trying to obtain OAuth 2.0 for using Youtube Data API v3?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

[image]

[The form to be filled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDYZZ.jpg)

I want to be a able to use the API from an IDE.

Comment: my api call is goona be from an ide using python code.not on a site at all so what should i put in application hompage . also what should i put in privacy policy link. any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Using the api from an IDE really doesn't matter.  Even if you have an installed application that is not hosted on a website you still need to enter this information. Users of your application still need to find the website of your company or application, and the information containing your privacy policy. Just point it to the home page for your application on your companies website and make sure to put up a privacy policy page as well there are several projects around that show format of GDPR compliant [privacy policy](https://www.privacypolicytemplate.net/).

The form in question is used for Oauth2 credentials.  When the user grants consent to your application they need to be able to find some required information about your application.

- Application homepage: Link to the home page for your application,
- Application privacy policy link:  Link to the privacy policy for your application.

## gsuite

If you are a gusite user you can set your project to internal only meaning that only users on your gsuite domain will be using it making verification a bit easier.

However i dont think that it matters you will still need to put something into these fiels.

[image]

Comment: my api call is goona be from an ide using python code.not on a site at all so what should i put in application hompage . also what should i put in privacy policy link. any alternatives.

Comment: Even if you have an installed application that is not hosted on a website you still need to enter this information.  Users of your application still need to find the website of your company or application, and the information containing your privacy policy.    Just point it to the home page for your application on your companies website and make sure to put up a privacy policy page as well there are several projects around that show format of GDPR compliant privacy policy.

Comment: this is for personal use. i have no company at all can i just link my github account on to this or is there an another option for personal use where u dont have to enter these.

Comment: If you are a gsuite user can set the project internal but its not going to matter this is the YouTube api the only way for you to authenticate is with the OAuth2 consent screen.  These values must be set to something.   I suggest dummy values.  Remember if your going to be uploading videos your videos will be private until the application has been verified.  Again setting it to internal only application may speed up that process but its only available for gsuite users.